# Why doesn't this mysql query seed a random number?

Tags: php, mysql

In the context of my PHP program, this query echoes a new database item every minute, which is exactly what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER BY rand(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/60)) LIMIT 1
```

However, when I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE dateused<44 ORDER BY rand(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/60)) LIMIT 1
```

the WHERE query works, but the number from rand doesn't seed. Every time this query is run, it results in the echo of a new database item.

Anyone got any ideas on how to get the number to seed for a minute? Or at least, a work around. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what is `$minute_ago`?

Comment: @zerkms Edited. Could be any integer.

Comment: "it results in a new database item." --- what does this mean? These selects cannot create anything in database

Comment: @zerkms Edited again. I meant echo on the page.

Comment: if you hardcode the value 44 - does it work as expected?

Comment: @zerkms Nope! I'm 95% sure the problem is in the query. Shall I upload the whole program? (Maybe should have done that from the start!)

Comment: @zerkms The random ordering and limit still work, the only thing is the 1 minute seed!

Comment: Your decision to use `ORDER BY random()` (seeded or not) is fundamentally wrong. Every query will perform full table scan, not much you can do about it.

Comment: @mvp It's a tiny project. Give me an answer?

Comment: It will not output a new row every minute, it will output a new row every query. Just because you give the same input to RAND() doesn't mean it will give the same output.

Comment: @Havenard Well I've just got this thing working, and unless my computer's powered by witchcraft (Windows, so that's debatable), it's giving me the same random number, even in different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, "As of MySQL 5.1.16, if a nonconstant initializer (such as a column name) is used as the argument, the seed is initialized with the value for each invocation of RAND()" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

But that is for versions of MySQL 5.1.16 and later. From MySQL 5.1.3 to 5.1.15, nonconstant arguments are not permitted. Before that, the effect of using a nonconstant argument is undefined.

So, if you are getting inconsistent results from a nonconstant argument, it is probably your version of MySQL.

I tried what you're doing on 5.1.47 MySQL and it worked the way you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: `SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER BY rand(MINUTE(NOW())) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Doing this won't make a difference. Both the values of MINUTE(NOW()) and ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/60) will stay the same during the same minute.